# Update existing and create new job schedule step in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

i already have one job with name Job1 and job step with job schedule name Daily.
I want to rename job schedule Daily name and one parameter in that schedule and also to create one more schedule with name Daily1.
Currently what i have is only checking of existing job schedule.

```
IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM [msdb].[dbo].[sysjobs] jb WITH(NOLOCK) 
            INNER JOIN [msdb].[dbo].[sysjobschedules] js WITH(NOLOCK) ON js.job_id = jb.job_id 
            INNER JOIN [msdb].[dbo].[sysschedules] sc WITH(NOLOCK) ON sc.schedule_id = js.schedule_id 
            WHERE jb.Name = 'Job1 ' and sc.name = N'Daily' )
BEGIN

--your code here

END
```

How can i achieve this update of existing job schedule and add new one in the same job

Comment: I would strongly advise against using `NOLOCK` here. It's a [bad enough habit](https://blogs.sentryone.com/AaronBertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere/) if you do it on your own tables, but a lot worse if you do it on system tables with the intent of modifying things later. You want a consistent view of the data here, far more than avoiding potentially blocking some other query for a millisecond.

Answer (score 0):

for renaming the schedule name you can run this:

```
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_update_schedule @schedule_id= your id , @new_name=N'new name'
```